# How to use jnlp with unsigned jar

Tags: jar, jnlp, unsigned, policy

In my application, I use the JNLP to start the project. But I don't want to sign the jars, because many of them come from customers.
Is there any away to run the JNLP with all permissions and unsigned jars? Can i use "Policy.setPolicy" to do this? How?